# android overridependingtransaction won't play animation

Tags: java, android, animation

I am having trouble getting my overridePendingTransaction to work on an activity class. The animation itself works properly if I use it as the enter animation on the second activity but doesn't work when I use it as the exit animation on the activity I want to actually run the animation on.

I have an asyncTask that downloads a database for me while the splash screen shows. Once complete the splash screen finishes and launches my main activity. Below is the code run in the splashactivity onCreate method that downloads the database and on completion closes the current task and launches my main.

```
AsyncSplashDatabaseLoading dbLoader = new AsyncSplashDatabaseLoading(this, 
                (TextView)findViewById(R.id.splash_tv_progress), 
                (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.splash_pb_progressbar),
                new AsyncSplashDatabaseLoadingHandler() {

                    public void onPostExecute(int result, Exception ex) {   
                        if (ex != null) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();

                            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
                            alertBuilder.setMessage(ex.getMessage())
                            .setNegativeButton("Exit", new OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    finish();                       
                                }
                            });

                            alertBuilder.create().show();
                        }
                        else {
                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(mainIntent);
                            finish();
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.stationary_item, R.anim.fade_scale_up); 
                        }
                    }
                });

        dbLoader.execute();
```

fade_scale_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <alpha 
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="400" />

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="100%"
        android:toXScale="200%"
        android:fromYScale="100%"
        android:toYScale="200%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="400" />

</set>
```

Activity definition in manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
    android:configChanges="locale"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
    android:theme="@style/Theme.No.Title" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="locale"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

style for Theme.No.Title

```
<style name="Theme.No.Title" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

The stationary_item.xml works proper as well as I have used that in other places but I will provide for the sake of knowing everything I am doing.

stationary_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="400" />
```

Things that I have tried:

1. I confirmed the animation itself works proper by using it on a different overridePendingTransactions method and it works correctly (or if I set the fade_scale_up as the enter animation and 0 as the exit it works proper)
2. Removed the async task and just ran the start of the activity in the onCreate method
3. Removed the Theme.No.Title from the style from the splash activity
4. Tried using single animations (ie translation or alpha only)
5. I tried using 0 for the enter animation so that only the fade_scale_up runs
6. I tried runOnUIThread with a runnable
7. However I have used different animations on the overrideTransactionPending and it WORKS proper (ie I used enter_in_left and exit_to_right provided below)

enter_in_left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" 
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="400" />

</set>
```

exit_to_right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="400" />

</set>
```

Any other ideas on what I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was able to figure out what the issue was. When the animations play, the enter animation of just showing the screen in a stationary position plays overtop the other view that is performing the exit animating. Hence if I do a fade in on the secondary view instead of a stationary item then the animations play together and the one view isn't blocking the exit animation of the activity that is quiting.

ie `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_scale_up);`

fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="800" />
```